# Extract chars from one string using regex python

Tags: python, regex

How do I extract a certain word after a certain character in regex python?

For example: 
    given = 'abcdefghijkl"mnop:"qfdf"gg"'

I want to get qfdf which is afer "mnop:" and before "gg". The given string is one string, no whitespace.

So far I can do \w+"mnop:" to get to qfdf"gg", but I don't know any \K function in python regex. I am also aware of using (?<=...), but this only takes a fixed width of characters.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?  http://regexr.com/ is your friend.

Comment: @codeforester is regexr.com for python? I thought this was for js..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage lookarounds:

```
(?<="mnop:")[^"]+(?="gg")
```

- The zero width positive lookbehind, `(?<="mnop:")`, makes sure the desired portion is preceded by `"mnop"`
- `[^"]+` matches one or more characters that are not `"`
- The zero width positive lookahead, `(?="gg")`, makes sure the desired match is followed by `"gg"`

**Example:**

```
In [6]: given = 'abcdefghijkl"mnop:"qfdf"gg"'

In [7]: re.search(r'(?<="mnop:")[^"]+(?="gg")', given).group()
Out[7]: 'qfdf'
```